# rbvmomi ignore invalid ssl certificate

Tags: ruby, ssl, vsphere

I am initiating a vsphere connection using rbvmomi (the ruby vsphere sdk). Does anybody know the flag to ignore unsigned SSL certificate errors?

```
1.9.2-p320 :003 > vim = RbVmomi::VIM.connect host: '10.13.37.1', user: 'boot', password: 'passwordhere:)'
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:632:in `start'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rbvmomi-1.8.1/lib/rbvmomi/trivial_soap.rb:56:in `restart_http'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rbvmomi-1.8.1/lib/rbvmomi/trivial_soap.rb:20:in `initialize'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rbvmomi-1.8.1/lib/rbvmomi/connection.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rbvmomi-1.8.1/lib/rbvmomi/vim.rb:36:in `new'
    from /Users/f/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rbvmomi-1.8.1/lib/rbvmomi/vim.rb:36:in `connect'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/f/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the documentation.

http://rdoc.info/github/rlane/rbvmomi/master/RbVmomi/VIM

```
:insecure 'true'
```

Comment: This is incorrect, :insecure 'true' will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The current [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rbvmomi/1.8.2/RbVmomi%2FVIM.connect) says we must pass an option to ignore this error.

```
insecure: true
```